# exporting data with custom field nantionality exports country id instead of country name

Tags: contacts, export

I have a custom field nationality and after upgrading to Civi 4.6.9, i noticed that when i export contacts with custom field nationality, first entry has the name but the rest are the country ids, see screen shot. 
[image: sample exported data]

I have also tested this on the demo site http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/ and it is the same problem [image: screen shot of data from demo civi]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thing happens to us. I just create an issue and proposed a patch as a provisional workaround.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17822

**[Edited]**

Seems that the issue is fixed for 4.6.12 version.